# What can I use here to simulate the ? (wildcard) generic in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, wildcard

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SpiShared;

namespace SpiController.Queue
{
    public class FakeQueueService : IQueueService
    {

        public FakeQueueService()
        {
            this.MessagesDeleted = new List<QueueMessage<?>>();
        }

        public IList<QueueMessage<?>> MessagesDeleted {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void Delete<T>(QueueMessage<T> message)
        {
            this.MessagesDeleted.Add(message); // doesn't work
        }

    }
}
```

At `Delete` I don't actually care what `T` is, all I care is that I want to store the `message` object provided. How do I do that with generics here? Is that even possible?

The actual `IQueueService` interface is:

```
using System;
using SpiShared;

namespace SpiController.Queue
{
    public interface IQueueService
    {

        Option<QueueMessage<T>> Poll<T>(Func<string,T> parser);

        void Push(string queueUrl, string message);

        void Delete<T>(QueueMessage<T> message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Instead, you can either make your entire class generic (and make `Delete()` non-generic), or add a non-generic base interface to `QueueMessage` and store that instead.

Comment: How do I make Delete non generic is QueueMessage is generic and a class?

Answer (score 4):

since you added a QueueMessage it would seems to me that you can just make your whole class generic based on T

```
namespace SpiController.Queue
{
  public class FakeQueueService<T> : IQueueService
  {

    public FakeQueueService()
    {
        this.MessagesDeleted = new List<QueueMessage<T>>();
    }

    public IList<QueueMessage<T>> MessagesDeleted {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Delete(QueueMessage<T> message)
    {
        this.MessagesDeleted.Add(message); 
    }

  }
}
```

Update:
The real question becomes why is QueueMessage a strongly typed class. Usually it is because you really know what messages you want to put on a certain queue (Say a particular queue always holds messages containing an invoice)

If you don't want to keep track of the type of message then just use a QueueMessage class. For example if i look at the QueueMessage class used in azure there is a non-generic version available.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.protocol.queuemessage.aspx

Comment: I can't, `T` could be anything and I don't really care what it is, that is the problem. In java I could just use ? and it would work.

Comment: QueueMessage is strongly typed because it has to be, for some cases it makes sense to know what kind of message I have and for others, like the `Delete` case, it doesn't. It wouldn't make sense to have a strongly typed IQueueService interface because it produces many messages, the actual interface is: https://gist.github.com/mauricio/e36f874830d9a4222ac1

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can use "T" everywhere.  Alternatively if you truly want a single list to contain all types you can make the "?" be "object" this will allow effectively any type to be stored there, and cast it later.  This is pretty common in the .net libraries.

Alternatively, use "T" everywhere as suggested previously (IE make the entire class generic)  but decide on some interface that T should come from, like this:

```
public class FakeQueueService<T> : IQueueService where T: ISomeInterface
```